# Norm of infinite (almost) stochastic matrix

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $A$ be an infinite matrix
$$A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & a_{1,3} & \dots \\
a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & a_{2,3} & \dots \\
a_{3,1} & a_{3,2} & a_{3,3} & \dots \\
\vdots & \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots
\end{pmatrix}
$$
with the following properties:

1. $0 < a_{i,j} < 1$
2. $ \sum_{i=1}^\infty a_{i,j} < 1$
3. $ \sum_{i=1}^\infty a_{i,j} \rightarrow 1$ as $j \rightarrow \infty$

In other words, it is almost like $A$ is an infinte stochastic matrix (with the additional property that its elements are nonzero, which could be useful if it allows us to invoke some type of Perron-Frobenius theorem). But instead of having each column sum to one, the sums converge to one as we move to the right. I would like to say something about the operator norm of $A$, defined as usual as
$$ \sup_{x \neq 0} \frac{||Ax||_2}{||x||_2} $$
In particular, is it the case that this operator norm is always $1$? This appears to be the case in some numerical examples I computed.

Comment: This doesn't hold for finite matrices, so I see no reason that it should hold for infinite matrices. For instance, consider
$$
\pmatrix{.5 & .5\\.1 & .9}.
$$
The operator norm of this matrix [is approximately 1.09](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=svd+%7B%7B.5%2C.5%7D%2C%7B.1%2C.9%7D%7D).